# iPhone application reset

Tags: iphone, ios4, geolocation, apple-push-notifications

I have a strange problem with my iPhone app. 
I use geolocation and push notification. Everything is ok, but I want to test from scratch on the iPhone (connected to xcode debugger)... and I can't re initialized the iPhone.

I explain: I remove the app from the iPhone, and after re-installing the app (with xcode or with iTunes), I launch the app, but iOS doesn't ask me to approve geolocation and push notification as it does the first time. In fact, it seems to 'remember' my choices.

As I need to debug this (Some users have problem on running app the first time), I'm blocked.

Thanks by advance for yours answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a place in the Settings app to reset Location permissions.

Comment: There is a place to allow or disallow location permissions globally or by app, but nothing to really reset permissions. And when an app is removed, it disappear from the list

Comment: My god! There's a reset at the bottom of general settings... I'm confused.